# Disable Compiz Shadow for a specific panel?

Tags: compiz, gnome-panel, panel

In compizconfig-settings-manager there's an option to enable/disable shadow of windows i.e. gnome-panel.

Is it possible to enable disable shadow only for a certain panel and not for all panels? Which options can I use beside any or none?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can exclude windows based on their title.

For example, to exclude the top panel from having a shadow we first need to find the title of the panel.

1. In the Window Decoration plugin, click on the add button to the right of the `Shadow windows` entry.
2. Change the `Type` to `Window Title`,click the `Grab` button and then click on the top panel. The title will probably be `Top Expanded Edge Panel`.
   Copy this and click   `Cancel`     (See [bug #584894 [image]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager/+bug/584894)).
3. Now in the `Shadow windows` entry, put in the following and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   `any & !(title=Top Expanded Edge Panel)`

   [image]

**Results**

- Before (with shadow):

  [image]
- After (without shadow):

  [image]